# XPM - Edit element menu

Tags: experience-manager, web8

We are using SDL WEB 8 for implementation of our site.
There is strange behavior with XPM.

Scenario is like this:

- Open web site
- Activate XPM on certain page
- Identify one item for editing (component presentation which component is inherited)
  [image: element identified]
- As it can be noticed, there is no information/icon on the border which gives options where to edit component (everywhere or local, or to see where it is used)
- Put a mouse pointer in the left part of top border
  [image]
- The text on the image gives information that mouse pointer is on good location, so user can perform left click on the mouse
  [image]
- And now this menu is shown.

In SDL Tridion 2013 this menu is visible automatic when some presentation is chosen.
Problem is the menu which cannot be visible automatic, so in most cases content editor can think that element is not predicted to be edited by XPM at all.

Any idea?

Comment: Not quite sure what the issue is based on your final sentence, is it simply that the 'component appears on ...' is simply not shown by default?   Once you've clicked 'edit this component ...' what happens?

Comment: Problem here is that this popup menu will not visible unless you click on line, which is sometimes difficult because you need to click on certain part.  Content editors will have to search where to click on the line. If component is shared they need this popup to know where component will be edited.

Comment: Hi Ljiljana, what browser and version are you using, what DXA version?

Comment: Hi, Elena. I have that issue with Firefox (45.0.1) and with Chrome (49.0.2623.87). We are using DXA 1.3